# using futures with flutter maps

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, async-await, future

I have this code which is supposed to loop through images to upload them to firebase, then take their links and put it inside the Product class so the product can have its images link. Then, upload the product too.
The problem is it doesn't wait for the upload to happen to insert its links to the product.
Code

```
 List<String> imgUrls = [];
 Future<void> loopThroughMap()async{
_map.forEach((storedImage, inGallery) async {
  if (!inGallery && storedImage != null && storedImage.path != null) {
    await GallerySaver.saveImage(storedImage.path);
  }

  String urlString = await FirestoreHelper.uploadImage(storedImage);
  imgUrls.add(urlString);
});
```

}

This function is called in here

```
`
    await loopThroughMap();
    print('FINISHED THIS ONE, imgs Urls length ${imgUrls.length}');
    for (int i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
    _editedProduct.imageUrl = imgUrls[i];
    else if (i == 1)
    _editedProduct.imageUrl2 = imgUrls[i];
    else if (i == 2)
    _editedProduct.imageUrl3 = imgUrls[i];
    else if (i == 3) _editedProduct.imageUrl4 = imgUrls[i];
    }`
```

The imgUrls list length is ALWAYS zero.
Could it be a problem with the map.foreach?

Comment: Does compiler reach your if statement? also I think you should remove the second asynk.

Comment: @P4yam it was a problem with foeach I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I changed the uploading from the ForEach loop to a for loop, and it works fine!

```
List<File> _listedImages = [];
  Future<void> loopThroughMap(){
    _map.forEach((storedImage, inGallery) async {
      if (!inGallery && storedImage != null && storedImage.path != null) {
        GallerySaver.saveImage(storedImage.path);
      }

      _listedImages.add(storedImage);
    });
  }
```

/////

```
for(var img in _listedImages){
              String url = await FirestoreHelper.uploadImage(img);
              imgUrls.add(url);
            }
```

After a lot of iterations, the only variable that was causing the error was the ForEach loop.